# How to recognise Android phone as a Bluetooth media device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-source

[image: This is how an android phone is recognised from another phone]

[image: This is how a Bluetooth headset is seen from a phone]

So my question is, I want to access Phone A's media and calls from phone B. I have complete control over phone B's OS. This is for a pet project and I'm using a rooted tablet I made. Phone B should be able to handle calls (accept/reject), and control music (Next/Play/Pause etc).

Now I know about Bluetooth Profiles, and that all phones have HFP/HSP and AVRCP/A2DP, but when we normally pair two phones, we can't access these profiles.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.Major   ,, this will help you

Comment: Included the images in question